# Is it possible to upload APNS Certificates to the azure notification hub programatically or via the CLI

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-notificationhub

We are investigating the azure notification hub, and while we have had success sending/receiving messages from it, we also require programatic configuration of the hub.

It seems that the only way possible to create the notification hub is via the azure cli with an azuredeploy.json ARM template like [this one](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-notification-hub/azuredeploy.json). However, I can't find any information about adding an APNS certificate to that.

Looking at the Automation Script generated from our hub, there is no evidence of the google firebase API key or the APNS certificate. Is this possible or do these need to be done through the azure portal at all times.

UPDATED: I have managed to create a notification hub namespace using the arm template with little issue, however I am getting a "bad request" (correlation id - 3faee649-7084-436d-8d7e-4a9c6f79cc4e) when trying to create the notification hub itself with the apns certificate.

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40842783/how-to-configure-the-apns-certificate-in-the-arm-template) is someone having a similar problem, however their key for the apns is a lot shorter than mine. I literally created a base64 string from the certificate file which is 5000+ characters wrong, I assume that is incorrect, but I can't figure out what value from apple is meant to go in here.

My template looks like this:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "Gcm.GoogleApiKey": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Google Cloud Messaging API Key"
      },
      "defaultValue": ""
    },
    "Apns.apnsCertificate": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "A certificate (in base 64 format) provided by Apple on the iOS Provisioning Portal"
        }
      },
      "Apns.certificateKey": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The Certificate Key provided by the iOS Provisioning Portal when registering the application"
        },
        "defaultValue": ""
      },
      "Apns.endpoint": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The APNS endpoint to which our service connects. This is one of two values: gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com for the sandbox endpoint or gateway.push.apple.com, for the production endpoint. Any other value is invalid"
        },
        "defaultValue": "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com"
      }
  },
  "variables": {
    "hubVersion": "[providers('Microsoft.NotificationHubs', 'namespaces').apiVersions[0]]",
    "notificationHubNamespace": "[concat('hubv2', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
    "notificationHubName": "notificationhub"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[variables('NotificationHubNamespace')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "type": "Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces",
      "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
      "comments": "Notification hub namespace",
      "properties": {
        "namespaceType": "NotificationHub"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "[concat(variables('NotificationHubNamespace'),'/',variables('NotificationHubName'))]",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "type": "Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/notificationHubs",
          "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
          "properties": {
            "GcmCredential": {
              "properties": {
                "googleApiKey": "[parameters('Gcm.GoogleApiKey')]",
                "gcmEndpoint": "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send"
              }
            },
            "apnsCredential": {
                "properties": {
                    "apnsCertificate" : "[parameters('Apns.apnsCertificate')]",
                    "certificateKey" : "[parameters('Apns.certificateKey')]",
                    "endpoint" : "[parameters('Apns.endpoint')]"
                }
            }
          },
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/', variables('NotificationHubNamespace'))]"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
  }
}
```

Comment: I can successfully create the namespace and hub if I remove the properties and credentials. But I need to add those programatically somehow. Either after the fact, or as part of this template.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the apnsCredentials property, the apsnCertificate is the base64 string from file and the certificatekey is your certificate password which needs to be a strong password. Are you following the same?

Also, is there an inner error message you see. If yes, what is it?

Thanks,
Amol

Comment: Is it the p12 file or a pem file that needs to be turned into base64. Is it literally the whole file converted into a byte[] then serialised into a base64 string. Does this not support having a blank password then? I don't think we put one on our cert. I can try and generate a new one with a password. Also, no there was nothing that I can see as an inner exception. I'm not sure if you can see more info using the correlation id - 3faee649-7084-436d-8d7e-4a9c6f79cc4e

Comment: I've tried again today using a .pem file with a password. (the only way I can see of adding a password is by exporting a .pem file). I've serialised the file to base64 so that is 5796 characters, and then added a strong password to this (auto generated - devilries799538'epistemologists) and am still getting bad request with no inner-exception.